# Деепричастный оборот + "перед тем как": пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

**Он, всякий раз заваривая чай(,) перед тем(,) как приняться за работу, возвёл это в статус ритуала.**
По моим ощущениям, 'перед тем как' входит в деепричастный оборот и вообще не требует запятой, но я не нашёл ни правила, ни примеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что правильной будет такая запись: *Он, **всякий раз заваривая чай, перед тем как приняться за работу,** возвёл это в статус ритуала.*

**Пояснение**

1. В данном случае к деепричастному обороту относится **придаточное инфинитивное** предложение, но оно **обособляется** от оборота. Даже интонационно прочитать эту конструкцию в одну фразу не получится, однако придаточное все-таки выделено вставочной интонацией (общим понижением тона, изменением темпа речи).
2. Если обратиться к правилам, то у Розенталя есть тема, когда деепричастные и причастные обороты **тесно примыкают** друг к другу и не разделяются запятой. Но это **не относится к придаточным предложениям**, имеющим подчинительный союз (тесного единства здесь не получится).

Розенталь, [Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113) (пункт 4, примечание 1)

Ср. (деепричастный оборот не отделяется запятой от причастия или другого деепричастия, к которому тесно примыкает): *Кучер, спавший **опершись на локоть,** начал пятить лошадей* (Гонч.); *Даже и Ласка, спавшая **свернувшись кольцом** в краю сена, неохотно встала* (Л. Т.); *Но Клим видел, что Лида, **слушая рассказы отца поджав губы**, не верит им* (М. Г.)...

3. Пример на эту тему из Грамоты.ру

Вопрос № 308649. Нужна ли запятая в приведенном предложении и почему?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Запятая не нужна.

*Нападавшие достали оружие, и Заяц из карабина начал стрелять в Волка и Лису, **обедавших сидя на траве слева у западного входа в пещеру.*** Подобные случаи соединения причастного оборота и деепричастного приводит Д. Э. Розенталь: *Кучер, спавший опершись на локоть, начал пятить лошадей* (Гонч.).

Мы видим, что **даже распространенный оборот** может не отделяться от предшествующего причастия запятой и произносится с ним в одну фразу.

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что запятая тут может не стоять перед союзом, а членить его, если по контексту мне надо подчеркнуть "перед тем"? *Он, всякий раз заваривая чай перед тем [а не после того], как приняться за работу...*

Comment: В общем случае это авторский выбор. Но нужно помнить, что при членении союза отношения меду главным и придаточным предложениями становятся взаимообусловленными. В данном случае мне показалось важным оформить придаточное отдельно, чтобы выделить его как вставку и подчеркнуть значимость самого деепричастного оборота.